# get value from curl response

Tags: php, cookies, curl, response

I am using CURL for get response from an web api. I am getting response but it is in string format like this:

> HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily Date: Fri, 16 Mar 2012 12:57:16 GMT
>   Server: GlassFish/v3 X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 Location:
>   http://demo.tdsarena.com/tds/ Content-Type: text/html;
>   charset=iso-8859-1 Content-Length: 0 Set-Cookie:
>   JSESSIONID=b869884w3w3r3r76dbd1a2bfd5d; Path=/tds Vary:
>   Accept-Encoding Connection: close

i am using following code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://demo.tdsarena.com/tds/j_security_check');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "j_username=XXX&j_password=XXX");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);



curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

i want to get cookie "JSESSIONID". but how can i get this. I have tried with $_COOKIE variable.

can anybody help me plz. thanks in advance.

Comment: but i am using post method by using CURLOPT_POST set to true in curl

Comment: The $_COOKIE variable is the wrong place to look. That will contain cookies passed when the PHP script was invoked, not cookies passed when curl_exec is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could parse the `$result` value and extract the cookie value using something like this:

```
if (preg_match('/Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=(.*?);/', $result, $matches))
{
    $cookieVal = $matches[1];
    echo $cookieVal;
}
```